# Nginx PHP setup: no input file specified

Tags: php, nginx

I inherited this web server with Nginx and I'm trying to get a new basic PHP site setup on here.

I've followed instructions here.
https://gist.github.com/GhazanfarMir/03bd1f1f770a3834d47274586d46ea62

I can read html files just file in my directory.    But for PHP files, I see this error in the webpage:

> No input file specified.

Not sure how to resolve this.  In my conf file I have this configuration for the PHP and root section:

```
location / {
    root      /var/www/mydomain.org/html;
    index     index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `root` statement?

Comment: above in the file.

  location / {
    root      /var/www/mydomain.org/html;
    index     index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
  }

Comment: What is in the `location @app { ... }` block?

Answer (score 3):

The error message "No input file specified" is almost always because the value of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` does not point to a file. The `location ~ \.php$` needs to know the document root, and the variable `$request_filename` is constructed by concatenating the document root with the current URI.

You have defined a document root for the `location /` block, but not the `location ~ \.php$` block. Usually, these are the same value, so a single `root` statement can be placed in the surrounding block, and inherited by all the `location` blocks that do not override the value.

For example:

```
root      /var/www/example.org/html;

location / {
    index     index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}

location @app {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: Thanks this worked...  so I can view php files and I got index.php to be the default document.   Now I am having problems, trying to make requests with ,php in the address bar.    This is what I have.. was looking at some other issues.

Comment: `
  root                  /var/www/example.org/html;
  index                 index.php;
  try_files             $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php$is_args$query_string @extensionless-php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  }

  location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
  }`

Comment: Please post this configuration file in a new question, with what you are trying to achieve and where it's going wrong.

Comment: okay, I figured it out on my own....  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Check the nginx error.log if you can find a clue as to what it might be.

As I use Windows 11, the problem was the `\` in the "root" folder path which caused a `GetFileAttributesEx()` error.

The solution was to replace it with `/`.

Maybe your problem is the root folder path, try using another one.

The path uses RegExp, try: `/var/www/example\.org/html`